# Personalpronomen für „jedermann“?

Tags: word-choice, personal-pronoun

> Jedermann hat viel zu tun. *_*_ muss priorisieren.

Ich suche ein Personalpronomen, das oben passt. Die Sätze sollen die gleiche Bedeutung wie der folgende Satz haben:

> Jedermann hat viel zu tun und muss priorisieren.

Ich möchte die Geschlechtsneutralität bewahren. Geht *er*? Gibt es bessere Möglichkeiten?

Comment: Es klingt schon "jedermann" ungewöhnlich. In welchem Kontext soll das denn sein?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich würde normalerweise sagen

```
Man muss priorisieren.
```

Auch wenn es in diesem Beispiel den Sinn vielleicht nicht mehr so trifft.

Comment: Oder "jeder"? Ist das auch möglich?

Comment: @Cerberus "Jeder" ist einfach eine kürzere, modernere Form für das doch recht antiquiert wirkende "Jedermann" (wie von @bernd_k angemerkt), und daher sicher auch möglich.

Comment: Wurdest du der Pronomen einfach wiederholen? "Jeder hat viel zu tun. Jeder muss priorisieren."

Comment: @Tim natürlich kann man das dann auch so verwenden, es würde dann besonders betonend, verstärkend wirken. Es kommt halt drauf an, ob man das möchte. Gerade rhetorisch kann man sich das gut vorstellen.

Answer (score 9):

Vielleicht geht auch

> Alle müssen priorisieren.

Es könnte aber sein, dass der Wechsel von Singular zu Plural zu abrupt ist. Ich finde allerdings auch "Jedermann hat viel zu tun." schon recht seltsam.

Vielleicht kann es auch ganz vermieden werden:

> Jedermann hat viel zu tun; es muss priorisiert werden.

Answer (score 6):

Vielleicht ist "man" hier das richtige Personalpronomen. Es ist ja schließlich das Indefinitpronomen:

http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/man

Die Etymologie von "man" ist dieselbe wie bei "Jedermann".

Ansonsten würde grammatisch wohl "er" passen, denn erstens ist "Jedermann" männlich und zweitens benutzen meines Wissens die meisten Sprachen das maskuline Geschlecht für unklare Fälle.

Answer (score 3):

Am besten einfach `jeder` sagen. `jedermann` klingt für mich ein wenig antiquiert und weckt auch sofort Assoziationen mit dem gleichnamigen [Theaterstück](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedermann).

Comment: Ich wusste nicht, dass _jedermann_ altsprachlich war. Was für einen Personalpronomen empfiehlst du für _jeder_?

Comment: @Tim *Altsprachlich* bedeutet *auf die alten Sprachen bezogen*, d. h. auf Latein und Altgriechisch. Du meinst wahrscheinlich eher *altmodisch* (out of fashion) oder etwas ähnliches.

Answer (score 1):

Das einzige *Personalpronomen*, das für "jedermann" passt, ist `er`. Ein `man` finde ich aber deutlich gebräuchlicher.